# What method is being called when I close an app

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I read all about the activity lifecycle and it's methods.

I still couldt find an answer:
When I close my app, from the "open apps" menu (in galaxy4 it's a long press on the home button, in nexus5 it's the right button ...) what method is being called? if any?

In other words, my activity is launching a service.
I want to terminate the service if the app (activity) is being closed.
(onDestory is not reliable at all as said many times here before)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: onStop() is always called

Comment: testit by yourself: set a breakpoint on both methods: onDestroy and onStop

Comment: you wll find answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163541/application-swipe-to-remove-app-recent-app-list

Comment: @BhaveshJethani is right...`onStop()` is always called indeed, but as soon as the app goes to background. So it's the wrong place to stop/unbind your Service. Seems that your Service needs to check whether "his" Activity is alive.

Answer (score 5):

onPause() is the only method that is called always. From onPause() state Android OS can kill this app for many reasons bypassing onStop and onDestroy. I don't think we can control this behavior of unexpected termination smoothly. Service can check for the state of the application periodically.

Answer (score 1):

You will go through `onPause()` then `onStop()`.  On pre-Honeycomb (API 11) devices, your app can be killed at any time after `onPause()` returns.  No more methods called, period.  Post-Honeycomb you will at least get `onStop()`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i want this behavious only when someone stops\kills my app.
As far as i understand - onStop will be called in many other cases, in which i dont want to terminate the service.

Comment: You won't receive any notification when the task manager kills your app.  You get `onStop()` when your activity is no longer in the foreground then your process can be killed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Locate with life cycle activity, one sugestion: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html

The system call the onPause(), after onStop() and last onDestroy(). You must analyze the best form for include your method. Pay attention in this moment.