# which android function gets called on swipe app closed?

Tags: android

What function to call in android to detect user has swipe closed the app? In general I wanna know how do I perform a task on swipe close of an android app

Comment: Related and possibly duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759941/what-method-is-being-called-when-i-close-an-app

Comment: From where should I called this isAppRunning() method to check if the app is swipe closed?

Comment: The safest way for you to solve this problem is to make your app "ready" to be filled as soon as the 'onPause()' is called. Since the other methods like `onStop()` are not guaranteed to be called. And like CommonsWare said, you can't detect the swipe and execute a task.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a service running, it may be called [with `onTaskRemoved()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved%28android.content.Intent%29), though I have never tried this.

Otherwise, nothing will be called on any of your classes.

Comment: No I don't have any service running. But I wanna know how do I perform a  task on swipe app close? Because onDestroy() doesn't gets called in all cases when I swipe close the app

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: "But I wanna know how do I perform a task on swipe app close?" -- AFAIK, you can't.