# Which method is called when app open? And when app closes?

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

I need to retrieve from a file one arrayList of Items, but i dont know where i need to put this retrieving code:

```
List<ItemCultural> cachedEntries = (List<ItemCultural>) InternalStorage.readObject(this, "arquivo.txt");
        regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().setListaDeItensCulturais(cachedEntries);
```

And I need to write this object when app closes by this command:

```
        InternalStorage.writeObject(this, "arquivo.txt", regraDeNegocioSingleton.getListaDeItensSingleton().getListaDeItensCulturais());
```

My InternalStorage Class:

I tried to Override onDestroy in my MainActivity but dont worked, and i put the retrieving code in my onCreate, but this method always called, not only time. Thanks!

Comment: This can help for the latter part of your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759941/what-method-is-being-called-when-i-close-an-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're referring about **onCreate** and **onDestroy** in an activity right,
when the activity starts call **onCreate** method and when the app closes can call **onDestroy** method.
So, if you want a class call when the Application starts you're talking about this (example):

```
public class RemindMe extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

     //add whatever you want

      }
 }
```

and add this class to your manifest like this:

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".Model.RemindMe"/>
```

and in your **MainActivity** add this lines:

```
     remindMe = (RemindMe)getApplication();
     remindMe.onCreate();
```

hope you can solve your issue :)

Comment: but onCreate is called so many times right? I need to retrieve informations of my text just one time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: nope this class is called only one time while the app starts,before the app run the other clases depending of your logic :), but if you want retrieve info of one textview you need retrieve a view