# How to run methods when someone exit the app?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making an app in which when user exits the application some methods will run but i cannot do it on onDestroy method because sometimes it is not working and if it is working then only the first line is executed so how to run method when user presses back button or remove it from the recent apps?

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759941/what-method-is-being-called-when-i-close-an-app), the `onPause()` method is what you want.

Comment: No, if user exits the application means it is not in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Service to do that

Here is what you can do if its **just about stopping service** when application is killed by swiping from Recent app list.

**Step 1:** Inside your Manifest file, keep flag `stopWithTask` as `false` for Service. Like:

```
    <service
        android:name="com.myapp.MyService"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

**Step 2:** Now in your `MyService` service, override method `onTaskRemoved`. (This will be fired only if `stopWithTask` is set to `false`).

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        //Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override this method in your activity that you are exiting from and do your task here:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do your exit task here
}
```

Comment: Yes i did it ...but what if the user do not press back button and just stop it without pressing back button. I mean like from background apps someone slide and stop the app

Comment: Then this might be the answer you were looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26882533/9611198

Comment: I already called same method in onbackpressed but i  to run it in other situation also when user do not use back button .